# How to find the number of subsets of a set X such as the sum of their elements is divisible by 3 in C?

Tags: c

I found this problem in an online judge. It doesn't seem very hard, but the online judge keeps returning me "Wrong Answer".

The first line of input contains an integer number N, 1 <= N <= 1000. The second line of input contains N different space-separated non-negative integer numbers, the elements of the set. All those numbers are lower than 2^31-1.

A single integer number, the amount of ways we can choose numbers, from the given set, so that their sums are a multiple of 3. The solution may be to big so output it modulo 10^9.

My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buffer[12000];
int restos[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
int C[1000][1000];
char *ptr;
int len;

int minimum(int, int);
int combinatorial(int, int);
void oldMain();
void binomialCoeff(int, int);
void solveCongruence(int , int *, int *, int *, int *);
void getAllPosibles(int , int , int , int *);
void getTheRestInt(char *, int *, int *, int *);

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    gets(buffer);
    n = atoi(buffer);
    gets(buffer);
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        getTheRestInt(pch, &restos[0], &restos[1], &restos[2]);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    int maximum = restos[0];
    if (restos[1] > maximum)
    {
        maximum = restos[1];
        if (restos[2] > maximum)
            maximum = restos[2];
    }
    else
    {
        if (restos[2] > maximum)
            maximum = restos[2];
    }

    binomialCoeff(maximum, maximum);

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        solveCongruence(i, &restos[0], &restos[1], &restos[2], &sum);
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}

//This method calculates the rest a string s modulo 3 and updates the the variables ri
void getTheRestInt(char *s, int *r0, int *r1, int *r2){
    int resto = strtol(s, NULL, 0) % 3;
    if (resto == 0)
        *r0 = *r0 + 1;
    else
    {
        if (resto == 1)
        {
            *r1 = *r1 + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            *r2 = *r2 + 1;
        }
    }
}

//This method solves the congruence 
void solveCongruence(int n, int *r0, int *r1, int *r2, int *sum){
    for (int i = 0; i <= *r0; i++)
    {
        if (n - (i + *r1 + *r2) <= 0){
            for (int j = 0; j <= *r1; j++)
            {
                int k = n - (i + j);
                if ((k <= *r2) && (k >= 0))
                {
                    if ((j + 2 * k) % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        getAllPosibles(i, j, k, sum);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//This methods updates sum with the number of sets associated with the triplet (i,j,k)
void getAllPosibles(int i, int j, int k, int *sum){
    unsigned long long int number = (combinatorial(restos[0], i)*combinatorial(restos[1], j)) % 1000000000;
    //printf("number : %d", number);
    number = (number * combinatorial(restos[2], k)) % 1000000000;
    *sum = (*sum + number) % (1000000000);
    return;
}

//Gets C[top][bottom]
int combinatorial(int top, int bottom){
    if (bottom>top)
        return 0;
    return C[top][bottom];
}

//Fill the C[i][j] array
void binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int minimal = minimum(i , k);
        for (j = 0; j <= minimal; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == i)
            {
                C[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                //Pascal's theorem
                C[i][j] = (C[i - 1][j - 1] % 1000000000) + (C[i - 1][j] % 1000000000);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Gets the minimum of two numbers
int minimum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a<b) ? a : b;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong while I'm reading from the standard input? Perhaps the problem is in the calculations mod 10^9, but I can't see it.

The mathematics behind my solution is in
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330532/how-to-find-the-number-of-subsets-of-a-set-x-such-as-the-sum-of-their-elements

Comment: do you know answer ? could you tell the answer ? may be 3 ?

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname: No, 42!

Comment: Have you printed each of the numbers as you read it to ensure you have the correct data being recognized by the program?  You should; it is the first step.  If you've not printed them, you can't tell whether you've got it right.  You don't seem to be using the value of `n` to determine whether you have the right amount of data.  Even with online competitions, you need to do basic data validation to ensure that your program is reading the data correctly -- even though you don't need to worry so much about deliberately malformed data.  You could use `scanf()` to read numbers, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error may come from the following line in the code you provided:

```
unsigned long long int number = (combinatorial(restos[0], i)*combinatorial(restos[1], j)) % 1000000000;
```

where `combinatorial(restos[0], i)` and `combinatorial(restos[1], j)` are binomial coefficients modulu 10^9 typed as int.

The problem is that the product `(combinatorial(restos[0], i)*combinatorial(restos[1], j))` is computed as an int and it triggers an overflow. Adding a cast to `unsigned long long int` changes the output:

```
unsigned long long int number = (((unsigned long long int)combinatorial(restos[0], i))*combinatorial(restos[1], j)) % 1000000000;
```

Another possible issue is the use of [`gets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/). Be aware that this function is deprecated as it is too vulnerable to buffer overflow. What if the user test a file larger than 12000 ? The advice of @jonathanleffler is a good one : try [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) !

```
// reading the number of int n
if(1!=scanf("%d",&n)){fprintf(stderr,"scanf failed to read int in stdin\n");exit(42);}
// scanf will skip the newline character, the first item can be read by calling scanf again
if(1!=scanf("%d",&resto)){fprintf(stderr,"scanf failed to read int in stdin\n");exit(42);}
```

Lastly, there is an approach which could be faster. In the code you provided, there are N(N+1)/2 binomial coefficients to be computed and stored and it limits the speed of the computation (the complexity is N^2). It can be shown that the number `r_0(N)` of subsets such that the sum of elements `e_i` is zero modulo 3 `sum_i^N e_i%3==0` can be computed in a single for loop of size N (linear complexity).

Let's say that at `n` the number `r_0(n)` of subsets such that `sum_i^n e_i%3==0`, the number `r_1(n)` of subsets such that `sum_i^n e_i%3==1` and the number `r_2(n)` of subsets such that `sum_i^n e_i%3==2` are known. If e_{n+1}%3==a, how to compute `r_0(n+1)`, `r_1(n+1)` and `r_2(n+2)` ? Possible subsets are:

- the one without `e_{n+1}`, which are already accounted for in `r_j(n)`
- subsets with `e_{n+1}`, which are unions of `e_{n+1}` and subsets accounted for in `r_j(n)`.
- the element `e_{n+1}` alone

The modulo should be updated accordingly:

```
 r_0(n+1)=r_0(n)+r_{3-a}(n)
 if(a==0){r_0(n+1)+=1;}
 r_1(n+1)=r_1(n)+r_{(3-a+1)%3}(n)
 if(a==1){r_1(n+1)+=1;}
 r_2(n+1)=r_2(n)+r_{(3-a+2)%3}(n)
 if(a==2){r_2(n+1)+=1;}
```

In each addition, a %1000000000 should be added to keep the result modulo %1000000000. This tricks works for 3 and any other number...The only requirement is to store and update `r_i`, an array of 3 ints in your case. The linear complexity should enable the use of much larger N.